# R how to use fun.aggregate in dcast to keep discrete values when widening dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, reshape2

I've been trying to use the `dcast()` function in `reshape2` to widen a large dataframe in R. However, I am not sure what to use for the aggregation function, `fun.aggregate` that `dcast` requires because I want to keep the discrete values of the `value.var`, whereas `dcast` insists on forcing `length` as the default, making every value dichotomous. For illustration, my data look like this:

```
x <- c("a", "b", "c")
y <- c("d", "e", "f")
num <- c(10, 20, 21)
data <- data.frame(cbind(x,y,num))

x y num
a d  10
b e  20
c f  21
```

After input `m <- dcast(data, x ~ y, value.var = "num")`, `dcast` returns the following DF:

```
  d  e  f
a 1  0  0
b 0  1  0
c 0  0  1
```

However, I want it to look like this:

```
  d  e  f
a 10 0  0
b 0  20 0
c 0  0  21
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. I meant to have the value at `a` `d` equal to 10, not 21. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to put the elements in quotation marks. I'll change that now.

Comment: `dcast(data, x ~ y, value.var = "num", fill = 0)` gives your desired output for me. Not sure where that first result came from, I get your desired output with `NA`s instead of 0s if I run the code you put in the question.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan you're right, it seems to work on smaller DFs. The data I'm trying to use on is much larger (n=6000), so that must be contributing to the issue. I guess I'll try cbinding everything together if I can't come up with a better solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can also switch to `tidyr`.

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- c("a", "b", "c")
y <- c("d", "e", "f")
num <- c(10, 20, 21)

df <- tibble(x, y, num)

df %>% 
  spread(y,  num, fill = 0)
```

output is:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  x         d     e     f
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a        10     0     0
2 b         0    20     0
3 c         0     0    21
```

Comment: I think that should work, but the `num` values aren't unique to each observation. Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: Ah, I see. Some of my `x` values are repeated, so I guess that won't work.

Comment: You can also create a index column. Like: `df %>% mutate(id = 1:now(df))  %>% spread(y, num, fill = 0)`